# If/Else block with variable number of conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, d3.js

```
var dots = svg.selectAll(".dot")
                  .data(data)
                   .enter().append("circle")
                  .attr("class", "dot")
                  .attr("r", 5)
                  .attr("cx", xDots)
                  .attr("cy", yDots)
                  .style("fill", function(d) {

                    cd = d;

                    //
                  if(m.options.hicColors != null ) {
                    if(d.hic <= m.options.cutoffs[0]) {
                        d.fillColor = m.options.hicColors[0];
                        return m.options.hicColors[0];
                    } else if (d.hic > m.options.cutoffs[0] && d.hic <= m.options.cutoffs[1]) {
                        d.fillColor = m.options.hicColors[1];
                        return m.options.hicColors[1];
                    } else if(d.hic > m.options.cutoffs[1] && d.hic <= m.options.cutoffs[2]){
                        d.fillColor = m.options.hicColors[2];
                        return m.options.hicColors[2];
                    } else if(d.hic > m.options.cutoffs[2] && d.hic <= m.options.cutoffs[3]) {
                        d.fillColor = m.options.hicColors[3];
                        return m.options.hicColors[3];
                    } else  {
                        d.fillColor = m.options.hicColors[4];
                        return m.options.hicColors[4];
                    }
                  } 

})
```

The program I am working on involves taking a set of shapes and coloring them based on two arrays, one containing the colors to be used, the other containing the cutoff values to decide which color is used. Previously, these were always 5 colors and 4 cutoffs, but now I need to accept arrays of any length. I'm not sure how I can accomplish this. Does anyone have any suggestions how I could complete this task?

Note that the length of the color array is always one more than the cutoff array.

Comment: Try with a loop, show us what you did, if there are problems.

Comment: Why don't you simply use a scale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a for loop and one if statement

```
if(m.options.hicColors != null ) {
    for (I = 0; I < m.options.hicColors.length; I ++) {
        if(d.hic <= m.options.cutoffs[i]) {
            d.fillColor = m.options.hicColors[i];
            return m.options.hicColors[i];
        }
    }
}

d.fillColor = m.options.hicColors[m.options.hicColor.length - 1];
return m.options.hicColors[m.options.hicColor.length - 1];
```

This should run in the spot of your old code as is.  Hope it helps.

Comment: What exactly is the point of `trueYet`? I mean, it works, but `trueYet` is never anything other than `false` because the only time it can get set to `true`, you return immediately anyway, so the `if (trueYet == false)` parts are unnecessary? Just wondering if I'm missing something

Comment: @jonhopkins it wasn't needed

Answer (score 1):

Loop the `m.options.cutoffs` array and do a function like that passing the actual index of your loop:

```
function analyse(hic, index){
    if(hic > m.options.cutoffs[index] && hic <= m.options.cutoffs[index+1]){
        return hic;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you know that you will always be checking for `d.hic` to be within a range and then using the upper bound of that range, a simple way to check a variable-length array is to work backwards from the end until you find a range that the value lies within.

```
var len = m.options.cutoffs.length;
for (var i = len - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    if (d.hic > m.options.cutoffs[i - 1]) {
        d.fillColor = m.options.hicColors[i];
        return m.options.hicColors[i];
    }
}
// if we got here, then d.hic falls within lowest range
d.fillColor = m.options.hicColors[0];
return m.options.hicColors[0];
```

This way, you don't even have to check the upper bound, because the previous iteration of the loop will only fail if `d.hic` is less than the upper bound for the current iteration.

Note that this could just as easily be done going from the beginning of the array to the end. I personally just use the backwards approach.

```
var len = m.options.cutoffs.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (d.hic <= m.options.cutoffs[i]) {
        d.fillColor = m.options.hicColors[i];
        return m.options.hicColors[i];
    }
}
// still need to catch the case where d.hic is higher than the highest range
d.fillColor = m.options.hicColors[len - 1];
return m.options.hicColors[len - 1];
```